# can't post an answer that contains &lt;

Tags: support, answers

I'm trying to post an answer that contains the following characters: '<','?','p','h','p',...'?','>'
I get an "an error occurred while submitting the edit" red error message.

See: [How to show user's answer and the correct answer on the same page after the score page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848420/how-to-show-users-answer-and-the-correct-answer-on-the-same-page-after-the-scor/34850901)

edit: testing here: `<?php echo '';?>`

Comment: It's already done. Check your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848420/how-to-show-users-answer-and-the-correct-answer-on-the-same-page-after-the-scor/34850901

Comment: Thanks @ketan, can you please fix the ends as well? I still can't save it when I fix it

Comment: It's also done. Check

Comment: thanks. Any idea why I can't edit it and you can?

Comment: Actually i don't know why this happens to you. I never get this type of issue before.

Comment: Might be you are behind corporate firewall / anti-virus? These tend to distrust what looks like code being sent in requests.

Comment: strange, here I can write the php tags but it doesn't show up

Comment: @Jongware Sorry i forget that. I have done it.

Comment: @Gavriel It's becuse you should make it code snippet. Either Press CTRL + K Or click on snippet icon on top.

Comment: If you mean the {} button, then I used it already, that's what indeted my code, and also it is displayed with the gray background. However it is possible that the corporate firewall does something here... I answered lots of questions so far, some php as well, and some from the office, but it is possible this is the 1st time when it's both php and from the office

Comment: The typically suggested work-around is to browse the site over HTTPS.